# Truncate half of very large file

Tags: powershell, windows-server

We've let a trace log run rampant on our productive system and it has grown to be nearly 50GB in size and caused the disk to run almost full. I've stopped the trace so the file won't grow any further. I don't need the whole file, but I also don't want to delete the whole thing and preserve the last few GB or so.

What I've thought about and dismissed:

- Truncating the file will loose the last few gigs of data I want to preserve
- PowerShell `gc | select -last 1000` scans forward and takes forever even on a 5 GB file (Interestingly enough, the command used over 8GB of RAM for the 5GB file before I killed it)
- Moving the file away for preservation is not feasible (it's a customer site)

Is there any other one-off shell magic command to maybe cut the file in half and get to the desired size by repeated halfings?

Or maybe a way to split the file up in chunks? (This would need to be done in-place, there is no room for a full copy of the file)

Comment: In Linux there is `fallocate --punch-hole` that drops data and makes the file sparse; you can't use it with NTFS though. I hope there's something similar for Windows and its filesystems.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski ty for the `fallocate` tip. This will still come in handy to me as i'm usually on linux :-)

Comment: Now I see `fallocate --collapse-range` might be even more useful in similar situation. Good luck with Windows.

Comment: It's amazing how many great tools there still are to discover for me, even after almost 10 years of linux experience. At this point it looks like I will just truncate the file on Windows and call it a day.

Comment: Also in Linux, you could do something like `tail -100000 [filename] > [new filename]; rm [filename]` to preserve the last 100,000 lines for analysis.

Comment: @MikeScott of that one I thought myself. Afaik, Powershell doesn't have a backwards scanning tail-like command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possibilities for splitting and joining a large file.

If you would accept a third-party free utility, then you could use
[HJ Split](http://www.hjsplit.org/),
or
[GSplit](https://www.gdgsoft.com/gsplit/),
but there exist many others.

If you would like to keep the file as whole and at the same time compress it into chunks,
you may use 7Zip, where on the Add to Archive screen you have the field
*Split to volumes*, specifying the number of bytes for each chunk and some
more options.

If you prefer a PowerShell script, you may use
[Split-File.ps1](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-functions-to-cb6bb05a)
which contains the functions of split by byte size and join:

```
Split-File "BigFile.dat" 10000000
dir BigFile??.dat | Join-File Rebuild.dat
```

If you are using the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), you may use the Linux commands
of
[split](https://linux.die.net/man/1/split)
and [cat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html).

If all you want is copy a part of the file, you may use this PowerShell
one-liner that uses the commands
[Get-Content](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6)
and
[Set-Content](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-6) :

```
$file = (Get-Content log.txt)[<from-line..<to-line>] | Set-Content logpart.txt
```

`Get-Content` also has the `-Tail` parameter that you asked about,
hopefully in a more efficient manner.

Comment: The mentioned tools are not a really an option. I cannot (or at least should not) install new software on the server. The link to 'Split-File.ps' is unfortunately pointing to another SU Question you were commenting on...

Comment: Oups - I fixed the link.

Comment: Thank you for the (updated) link to the PowerShell script. As mentioned in my question, I cannot create a (split-up) copy of the file, as the disk is already running low. The script should remove each chunk of processed data as it goes on which turns the question again to how to remove the first GB (or so) of a file.

Comment: Can't you use an external disk?

Comment: No, I cant. It's a customer's machine located... somewhere on the internet, from my perspective

Comment: I added one more PowerShell command which might help.

Comment: The `-Tail` option for `Get-Content` seems to reverse the scanning order. With that, I was able to extract the last 100k lines into a separate file. Now I can safely remove the rest. Thank you

Comment: Question talks about 50 GB files and all the PowerShell solutions mentioned are buffering entire data into memory. That will be very inefficient. There has to be a solution using file system APIs...

Comment: @GeorgeChakhidze: Buffering disk-to-disk is impossible - data has to transit by RAM.